# excel VBA - modify table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to achieve a modification to an existing table
The original sheet looks like this:
Original[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL7pE.png)

and the final result should look like this
Final look[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZivAa.png)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide code blocks over external links when possible. You can add code blocks with backticks `like so`.

Comment: Hi Asaf. What does your code look like at the moment? What are the issues with it?